# Arangodb- Getting fullCount in AQL as part of normal limit query

Tags: arangodb

How do I get full count as part of the normal limit query.

I am looking for executing this in the Queries section in the GUI

Regards,
Sajeev

Answer (score 1):

You can set the flag `fullCount` in the options for creating the cursor to true. Then the result will have an extra attribute with the sub-attributes `stats` and `fullCount`.

You then can get the the `fullCount`-attribute via `cursor.extra.stats.fullCount`. This attribute contains the number of documents in the result before the last `LIMIT` in the query was applied. see [HTTP documentation](https://docs.arangodb.com/current/HTTP/AqlQueryCursor/AccessingCursors.html)

Keep in mind, that the `fullCount` attribute only appears if the number of results before `LIMIT` is higher then the results after.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am looking to run this using AQL in the web UI queries section.

Comment: This is currently not supported. I discuss this with a colleague, maybe we implement this in the near future.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your reply